# How to access assets directory in an aar library?

Tags: android, assets, aar

I created an aar library that contains an assets folder.
The folder is archived correctly, but I can't access the assets.

```
Assets a = new Assets(this.context)
```

references to the app's assets.

```
AssetsManager am = this.context.getAssets()
```

This references to the correct files, but I can't get a file object of a directory.

My hierarchy is:

- assets

  - de-de

    - acoustic

      - fileA
      - fileB

      ...

What I need is a File object for the acoustic **directory**.
I think I can use

```
InputStream is = am.open("the/path");
```

and convert it into a file object. But it doesn't work with directories.

Does someone know how to achieve this?